# I should get output in xml format

Tags: php, mysql, xml

```
<?php

$sql    = "SELECT xxxx FROM xxxx";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $jobtitle = $row["xxxx"];
        echo $jobtitle . "<br/>"; //output should be in xml format as given below
    }

}
```

In the above example code I am printing jobtitle as simple text using `echo`.

But I want the output in XML format; That is I should get output similar to:

```
<all>
   <jobtitle>job1</jobtitle>
   <jobtitle>job2</jobtitle>
</all>
```

Curently I get output as:

```
job1
job2
```

Comment: where do you say to your program you want <all><jobtitle>...?

Comment: inside while loop.....we have to give code which prints...the out put in xml format....i dont know how i can print output in xml format

Comment: but you don't ask your program to echo the markups, so there will be no xml.

Answer (score 0):

It won't automatically insert the xml tags you want, you need to echo them in front of and after the job, the following does just that:

```
    echo header('Content-Type: application/xml');
    $sql = "select jobtitle from jobslist";
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
     if($result)
     {
       echo "<all>\n";
       while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
       {
         $jobtitle = $row["jobtitle"];
     echo "<jobtitle>$jobtitle</jobtitle>\n"; //output should be in xml format as given below
       }
       echo "</all>\n";
     }
```

Specifically the line that has the $jobtitle echoed, just needs to be modfied (along with starting/ending the <all> and </all>

```
echo "<jobtitle>$jobtitle</jobtitle>\n";
```

Comment: I think it's because they're outputted as ``html`` tags instead. :)

Comment: I think you need to debug differently - did you forget to be using "view source" on the page? If you are looking in your browser, it will show the outputted text only (without the tags, same way <div>text</div> only shows the word "text"), but "view source" and you will see the raw XML

Comment: I'm going to start adding the comments to my own thread, since I'm the one answering you now. You now need to make sure to escape the "&" in your XML, so just make sure to str_replace("&","&amp;",$jobtitle);             echo "<jobtitle>".str_replace("&","&amp;",$jobtitle)."</jobtitle>\n";

Comment: By the way, you CANNOT debug XML in your browser by loading the page, you MUST right click and select "view source". Only then can you truly see the RAW CONTENT

Comment: I see confusing commentary and I saw a <pre>... can you elaborate. Why do you need the orininal content to output in the browser. Why are you outputting your results as XML? By its very nature, XML is not viewable in your browser by just loading the page (look at an RSS feed, it never just "loads"). No, I think you may have mis-information about how to look at your XML, if that is in fact the goal. (you aren't just wanting to output it inline with your HTML?). Next steps. Make sure you escape all entities (& with &amp;) then view source and if it looks like clean XML you are good.

Answer (score 0):

You must add xml tags to wrap your database results and also send proper header for xml. I added also  so that you don't have to worry about xml errors while parsing  output

```
    if($result){
        header ("Content-Type:text/xml"); 
        $xmlstring='<?xml version="1.0"?>\n';
        $xmlstring='<all>\n';
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
              $xmlstring.='<jobtitle><![CDATA['. $row["jobtitle"].']]></jobtitle>\n';

          }
       $xmlstring.='</all>';

       echo  $xmlstring;
       }
```

Comment: how does your xml look like?

Comment: The only problem with this is that header ("Content-Type:text/xml");  should be at the top, before the while loop and any echo. Suggested: if($result){ header ("Content-Type:text/xml"); ...

Comment: Oh, both that AND you for some reason have a <pre> at the top of your page... get rid of that. BTW, my answer below was verbatim this exact answer, so grrrr

Comment: Getting close! Now just remove the <pre> at the beginning, and \n at the end ;) (http://jklconsol.com/jobsnew/getJobCountries.php)

Comment: what do you mean "but it should be on original output" ?

Comment: Use this to validate your XML (I entered the address of your previous page): http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjklconsol.com%2Fjobsnew%2FgetJobCountries.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: You are so close, just do the str_replace("&","&amp;",$row["jobtitle"]) that I recommended

Comment: or put all $row["jobtitle"] in <![CDATA["  "]]> so that you don't have to worry about every character possible to come in string 
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

Comment: Yup - either will work. <![CDATA[" "]]> is ideal I hope you don't pull an all nighter, you're almost there. Basically echo '<![CDATA["' .$row["jobtitle"] .' "]]>'

Comment: <?php
      header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
      include_once("includes/application_includes.php"); 
      $jobslist = sqlquery comes here;
    if(!empty($jobslist)) {
    $jobsinfo = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    $jobsinfo.='<all>';
     foreach($jobslist as $jobslistdata) 
        {
      $jobsinfo.='<jobs>';
                      $jobsinfo.='<jobtitle>'.contentparsing($jobslistdata['jobtitle']).'</jobtitle>';

                    $jobsinfo.='</jobs>';
    }
    $jobsinfo.='</all>';
        }
         echo $jobsinfo;
         ?> ...i got it..thank you all for ur kind help

Comment: no problem, accept the answer you think helped you the most since there is more than one correct answers

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the simple fact that you're not appending the `XML` tags to your output. A simple approach to make it work as expected to would be the following:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: application/xml'); ?>
<?php
    $sql = "select jobtitle from jobslist";
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
    if($result) {
        echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>', "\n";
        echo '<all>', "\n";
        while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
            echo '    <jobtitle>' , $row["jobtitle"] , '</jobtitle>' , "\n";
        }
        echo '</all>', "\n";
    }
?>
```

Also, [here's a test I conducted on Codepad.org](http://codepad.org/sKUJjZx7) which shows what the changes do.

Answer (score 0):

For your pretty simple XML output, you can easily do it with the help of [`SimpleXMLElement`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/SimpleXMLElement):

```
$all = new SimpleXMLElement('<all />');

$sql    = "SELECT xxxx FROM xxxx";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
while ($result && $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $all->addChild('jobtitle', $row["xxxx"]);
}

echo $all->asXML();
```

Example output (beautified):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<all>
    <jobtitle>job1</jobtitle>
    <jobtitle>job2</jobtitle>
</all>
```

I also suggest you take a look into the PHP manual that has more resources to offer how to create, manipulate and output XML: [Basic SimpleXML usage](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic).